# What is the React Sigma style file mentioned in their setup documentation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sigma.js

This is my first time making graphs in React so I'm following the guide and documentation. I have no prior experience with graphology, sigma.js or [react-sigma](https://sim51.github.io/react-sigma/) (I know how to use normal React).

The [setup documentation](https://sim51.github.io/react-sigma/docs/start-setup/) says:

> Import the React Sigma style file in your application. Example : `import "@react-sigma/core/lib/react-sigma.min.css"`

**What are style files? CSS? How can I make one? I can't find any documentation. Is it something basic from a previous library?**

**[image: Step I cant figure out]**

Honestly I'm finding it very hard to learn sigma.js and insert it in my react website. I can't find any guides. Are there any? I just want to start with a simple graph and learn from there.

Comment: Forgot to add the screenshot source: https://sim51.github.io/react-sigma/docs/start-setup

Comment: @Emile, which part of *"What are style files?"* is unclear? How is this a well scoped question within the context of the npm package? Or of react, for that matter? It's way too broad by [SO] standards and it already has an answer [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS).

Comment: @a.h.g. you've misunderstood the question and are focusing too much on a single detail.

Comment: @Emile, you might be right, but at this point I can't help but doubt it. Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation refers specifically to their own CSS file which must be imported in a React app like they are showing in the example:

```
import "@react-sigma/core/lib/react-sigma.min.css";
```

*Disclaimer: depending on your React app setup, the way to import a CSS file might differ.*

---

The example in the documentation was broken when I wrote this answer. I opened [an issue on the react-sigma repo](https://github.com/sim51/react-sigma/issues/23) and it was fixed since then.

When I tried it, some dependencies were missing and some changes were needed.

```
npm install @react-sigma/core sigma graphology graphology-types lodash
```

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import Graph from "graphology";
import { SigmaContainer, useLoadGraph } from "@react-sigma/core";

// Import the style file here
import "@react-sigma/core/lib/react-sigma.min.css";

export const LoadGraph = () => {
  // first change to their example
  const loadGraph = useLoadGraph();

  // also wrapped their graph instantiation side-effect with useEffect
  useEffect(() => {
    const graph = new Graph();

    graph.addNode("first", {
      // Required position
      x: 1,
      y: 1,

      size: 15,
      label: "My first node",
      color: "#FA4F40"
    });

    // Calling the function that was missing from the example
    loadGraph(graph);
  }, [loadGraph]);

  // Returning null to get a valid component
  return null;
};

export const DisplayGraph = () => {
  return (
    <SigmaContainer style={{ height: "500px", width: "500px" }}>
      <LoadGraph />
    </SigmaContainer>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit react-sigma-example]

Note that I used TypeScript for the example, which gives insightful error messages since *react-sigma* provides its own types.

Then it was clear that the `useLoadGraph` hook wasn't used properly since it doesn't accept any parameter and it returns a function accepting a `graph` parameter. This can be confirmed with the [API documentation](https://sim51.github.io/react-sigma/docs/api/core/#useloadgraph).

I also figured that [lodash](https://lodash.com/) was missing from errors in the developer console.

---

*Please refer to [the documentation](https://sim51.github.io/react-sigma/docs/start-setup/) as it's now up-to-date.*

Comment: I'm the author on the lib, and I updated the documentation on the project.
Thanks to you Emile & Santiago , the project quality is going forward and it will help a lot new users !

Comment: Great. Thx everyone!